# BTS ESB chaing the application integration type

Tags: integration, biztalk, biztalk2006r2, esb-toolkit-2.0

I've been doing Google around to find out the solution for the question "how can I change application integration style from point-to-point to a bus-bus in BizTalk ESB 2.0?".

Please could any one suggest me answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Place the ESB as HUB and Spoke among all the external applications.